# add commas to wordpress-generated list

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a small function that modifies links created by the Wordpress get_the_term_list function but cannot work out how to add commas (or another separator) between list items. My attempt adds commas but also adds one at the end of the list, which I don't want. How do I remove that last comma?

```
$terms = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'portfolio_cat', '', '/' ));
$terms = explode("/",$terms);
for($i=0; $i<count($terms); $i++){ 
echo "<a href='urlhere/$terms[$i]'>" . $terms[$i] . "</a>";
$total = count($terms);
if ($i != $total) echo', ';
}
```

Comment: Try with `if ($i < $total-1)`. As PHP array's indexes start at 0 (so 1-1), $i last value will be $total-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close...but the issue is because you're starting `$i` at `0`, and `count()` starts at `1`. So, to fix the issue, just add a `-1` to your total:

```
$terms = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'portfolio_cat', '', '/' ));
$terms = explode("/",$terms);

for($i=0; $i<count($terms); $i++){ 
    echo "<a href='urlhere/$terms[$i]'>" . $terms[$i] . "</a>";
    $total = count($terms) - 1;

    if ($i != $total) { echo', '; }
}
```

Comment: Ah-ha, I can't count! Worked great. Thanks.